# Active directory custom authentication

Tags: windows, authentication, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, custom-authentication

I had created a sub-authentication package for Windows-7 login. It worked successfully for local account logins.
I then tried to implement same sub-authentication package for active directory in Windows server 2008 r2. I placed my DLLs in `Windows\System32\` folder and modified registry values of Kerberos as [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799bc2cd-4452-4286-8127-a5753912e17f%28v=ws.10%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#BKMK_KerbSSP) Microsoft document explains for sub-authentication dll.

The value I set was in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Kerberos` Value: `Auth0` set to `C:\Windows\System32\SubAuth.dll` (am I right here?).

But while authenticating I notice that my sub-authentication package doesn't get called as I don't get asked for the second factor while authenticating user on client machine against AD.

Am I missing something in setup or there is something I have to change in my Sub-authentication package.

Let me know if I have missed on any information here.

PS: Sub-authentication package is developed as per the Microsoft's Credential Provider documentations (in Msv1_0SubAuthenticationFilter routine).

Comment: Hello, how were you able to solve this? I have this same issue and the answer here doesn't help too.

Comment: @OlorunfemiAjibulu sorry for the delay. I have answered my question. Hope that helps you. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is by design - Msv1_0SubAuthenticationFilter routine from kerberos\ssv1_0 subauth package will not be called for cached domain interactive logon.

For interactive logon сall chain will be something like:

```
LsaApLogonUserEx2->MsvSamValidate->MsvpSamValidate->MsvpPasswordValidate
LsaApLogonUserEx2->MsvSamValidate->MsvpSamValidate->Msv1_0SubAuthenticationRoutine
```

But for cached interactive logon сall chain looks like:

```
LsaApLogonUserEx2->MsvpPasswordValidate 
<and there is no call to Msv1_0SubAuthenticationRoutine here>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what I have asked in question, I needed to hack around in Microsoft's authentication package.

Here's what I did.

To communicate to active directory & make the authentication w.r.t. AD, I had to do it before hand in credential provider.

So my control flow for the solution goes like this in Credential provider:

1. Check whether user is connected to network.
2. If yes, then communicate with AD server, which is predefined & validate user against AD entry.
3. If user is validated then ask for 2nd factor in credential provider only & then on successful validation, pass user to sub-auth module & bypass 2nd factor in sub-auth.
4. If user is not connected to network, then validate with sub-auth module.

So basically, I had to first perform 2nd FA if the user needed to validate against AD & perform password authentication later on in the sub-auth module.